# Issues with apache worker with CA bundle (Error (20): unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, httpd.conf, pki

In our setup, we have several thousand users pounding a linux server running rhel 5.8 using apache (httpd-2.2.3-65.el5_8, mod_ssl-2.2.3-65.el5_8). Our users use PKI to login to the system. There are 5 CAs on the server. When we use apache prefork model, everything works fine. However when we switch to worker model, most of the requests goes through fine, but we are getting a lot of errors in the `ssl_error_log` file such as the following:

"[error] Certificate Verification: Error (20): unable to get local issuer certificate"

If we run worker model with a single CA, we don't get this error. This error does not occur when using the prefork model. This does not happen with CA bundles with worker `ThreadsPerChild=1`. Only the combination of worker (`ThreadsPerChild>1`) with a ca bundle instead of single CA causes this to happen.

This is our worker configuration on the apache configuration file:

```
<IfModule worker.c>
ServerLimit     250
StartServers         20
MaxClients         2050
MinSpareThreads     20
MaxSpareThreads     50
ThreadsPerChild     10
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

And the prefork setting is:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit     2048
MaxClients      2048
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

Is there a known issue with running multiple CA's with worker as opposed to using prefork, or do we need to adjust our worker configuration correctly to get the desired behavior?

Comment: new user tip: if you find some answer helpful, you may accept/upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet it's worker-specific, and not depending on configuration, but rather worker's design concept. It's possible it was fixed with apache 2.4 . Do you keep whole chain with each certificate in the same file, or you use virtualhost certificate and CA chain in separate files? AFAIR it's possible to use two directives for CA certs, or other single one directive pointing to a file containing vhost certificate AND chain.

To conclude - if something helps, it will be reorganizing data in certificate files rather than configuration. Anyway it's quite strange that you use separate CA certs, you should probably work it out, create one highest level CA ( e.g. provider (yours) CA ), and issue certificates for various websites some level below, possibly with CAs in the middle of chain. That way you'll be able to possibly revoke all certificates of particular CA - and that's the way it usually goes with professional, high-scale certification companies and organizations. As you report issue does not shows when using with single thread / single CA, I guess you're able to do it that way.

Personal congrats for using X509 authencation/authorization, that's nice someone uses it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have created 5 different independent CAs for testing purposes, which is similar to our client usage. There are no chains in CA hierarchy. There is a single virtual host for PKI and all 5 different CAs keys are kept in a single file. Server certificate is kept in a separate file.

Comment: apparently splitting the CA bundle into multiple files and using  SSLCACertificatePath to specify the directory containing CA certificates, solved this problem. Its strange though.